# How i can patch method and return back incoming arguments in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I have question about pytest mock patch. 
I don't know how i can patch method which execute raw SQL .

I have common method which fetch results.

```py
def execute(query):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
    return dictfetchall(cursor)
```

How it using in project:

```py
def some_method():
    query = "some raw SQL"
    return execute(query)
```

In test case i want get raw query string from executer and compare it with some example

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_publisher_intensity2():
    publisher_id = 1
    query = publisher_intensity2(
        #
        publisher_id,
        date_from,
        date_to,
    )
    assert query == "SOME SQL"
```

In general i want get incoming arguments from executor in test case

I'm using pytest and django_db

How i can do that?

Comment: patch `execute` in the file where `some_method` is used to return the value of query as opposed to the actual query.

Comment: I don't understand how exactly i should do it. Can you write a little example?